# Update field to transformed/mapped value of another field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapping

I have a collection of, for example `FieldA` (string), `FieldB` (string). I now want to update the entire collection, such that `FieldB` gets set to the result of passing `FieldA` of the same document to a transform function, ie, something like this:

```
updateMany({}, ['$set': {'FieldA': myTransform('$FieldB')}])
```

where myTransform is a JavaScript Function. In my case, it would simply convert the string-value of FieldA to integer, as to get rid of potential leading 0s.

Obviously, this does not work: It would simply call myTransform with a constant argument of '$myField', not the actual value of the field in the current document.

How can I change this query to *efficiently* do what I want, ie set a field of the currently considered document to a mapped value of another field on the same document? Do I absolutely have to write two queries, one to get the values, and one to update them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your js function with `$toInt` in an aggregation function. After populating `FieldA` by `$addFields`, use `$merge` to update back to your collection.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "FieldA": {
        $toInt: "$FieldB"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$merge": {
      "into": "collection",
      "on": "_id",
      "whenMatched": "replace"
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5BOXkCIhnWZ) for your referenc.